# How to match a ByteString with a NUL byte?

Tags: regex, haskell, bytestring

I want to split a huge (12GB), lazy ByteString with a Regexp that matches, among other things, a NUL `\x00` byte.

I know that it should be possible, given that I've been able to split a sample string with python:

```
 >>> from re import split
 >>> split(b"\x00", b"a\x00b")
 [b'a', b'b']
```

I'm not sure that it could work, but I wanted to give it a try with Haskell, since it should be able to read the file lazily and work on it without allocating memory for the whole string. (It should be easier than working on it chunk-by-chunk, writing a parser or tweaking the original program to output something less broken).

Haskell regex matching on ByteStrings is easy enough:

```
("a\x01\&b" :: ByteString) =~ ("\x01" ::ByteString) :: (ByteString, ByteString, ByteString)
("a","\SOH","b")
```

But doing the same with a `\x00` yields something weird:

```
("a\x00\&b" :: ByteString) =~ ("\x00" ::ByteString) :: (ByteString, ByteString, ByteString)
("","","a\NULb")
```

Please note that it's not failing to find a match (otherwise the first element of the tuple would be the original string), instead it's matching on an invisible/implicit `\x00` apparently.

Any hints?

Comment: I just realized that this only happens with `Text.Regex.Posix` and not with `Text.Regex.TDFA`... now testing with PCRE

Comment: Weird, installing `regex-pcre` makes `Text.Regex.Posix` unable to be imported. Anyhow pcre doesn't even have instances for ByteStrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man 3 regex`:

> regcomp() is supplied with preg, a pointer to a pattern buffer storage area; regex, a pointer to the null-terminated string and cflags,
>          flags used to determine the type of compilation.

So, the Regex `"\x00"`, just like `"\x00whatever"`, being evaluated as a null-terminated string, is de-facto equal to `""`, the empty string.

and matching anything on the empty string, will always yield `("", "", your_original_string)`.

The best solution is to probably use `Text.Regex.TDFA`, which doesn't exhibit this behavior as I mentioned in a previous comment

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use regexes here. `Data.ByteString` already provides the function [`split`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v%3asplit), which lets you split a ByteString on any byte value.

Comment: Thanks, but this was only a reduced test case, the original regexp byte string was "\x00.{5}"